# Max body size for http inbound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

Is there a way to configure the max size the post's body using a http:inbound-gateway and the http body of a response using a http:outbound-gateway?

thanks in advance
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `http:inbound-gateway` is fully based on the Servlet API, so whatever your servlet container can configure for the *post max size* is there for you. Nothing to do from Spring Integration perspective on the matter.

The `http:outbound-gateway` is fully based on Spring Web's `RestTemplate`, which can be configured with any `ClientHttpRequestFactory` implementation. So, whatever that one can do for you for body response can be configured only there. Again: nothing to do from Spring Integration perspective on the matter.